# Rails - Randomise record but retain the order by date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am pulling data into database from 4 different sources and when they are saved they get assigned `created_at` by rails.

When I am displaying the data I want to display the latest records first so I am using the following code to fetch the records by `created_at desc` and with the help of gem `kaminari` records are displayed via pagination.

```
@stats = Stats.page(params[:page]).order('created_at desc').per(10)
```

The problem I am facing with this approach is not all sources get equal exposure for example since `source A` data got pulled first and then the `source B` data got pulled second on same day, on the website all records of source A will be displayed first and then all records of source B will appear.

So my question is, how can I display the records by date and randomize the records for that date so all sources can get equal exposure. Is there an in build rails function that can help in this? If not then what is the best way to achieve the outcome I am looking for? Something like this

```
Date (August 29th)
Record 1 -  (Belonging to Source A)
Record 2 -  (Belonging to Source E)
Record 3 -  (Belonging to Source D)
Record 4 -  (Belonging to Source B)
Record 5 -  (Belonging to Source E)
Record 6 -  (Belonging to Source D)
Record 7 -  (Belonging to Source A)



Date (August 28th)
Record 1 -  (Belonging to Source E)
Record 2 -  (Belonging to Source D)
Record 3 -  (Belonging to Source A)
Record 4 -  (Belonging to Source B)
Record 5 -  (Belonging to Source A)
Record 6 -  (Belonging to Source D)
Record 7 -  (Belonging to Source A)


...
...
...
```

These records are displayed for last 6 months

Comment: Since an amount of records is relatively small, one might use [`Array#shuffle`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-shuffle).

Comment: Wont that break the order by date? each source has over 20 records and there are 4 sources involved, the data is fetched every day and it is displayed for last 6 months so the data is pretty huge

Comment: There is no way to magically sort the data from different sources. If you want to preserve a date/time order, join everything into a single array and use [`Array#sort`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-sort).

Comment: I am not looking for a magical way either :) if I use the shuffle how can i retain the date? I am guessing that will be another loop in the view?

Comment: @Saadia _"if I use the shuffle how can i retain the date"_ – that's easy: group the records by date and shuffle each group on its own. If you want get the same (random) result each time, you could seed the RNG with a value unique to that group.

Comment: @Stefan thanks, I was thinking the same, i am now looking for an example

Comment: You can also change the order clause to 'DATE(created_at) desc, RAND()' but you will need to have a date aware pagination to make sure you retreive all records for a given date at once

Comment: There's no rails method to do such thing, which DB are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using postgresql you could do something like

```
Stats.select('*, random() as random')
  .order('date(created_at) ASC')
  .order('random ASC')
```

If you provide more than one order statement to your SQL it'll order the data with using the first column (in this case `created_at` casted to date) and if any of those values are the same (and this is what we wanted, and caused by casting `created_at` to dates) the second order will be used.

But! Every time your page is refreshed - you can see different results and that's confusing and really bad UX.

So I would recommend adding one new column (called for example `random`) and assigning random number on creation. Then you can just do:

```
Stats.order('date(created_at) ASC').order('random ASC')
```

One last problem is that it's not DB agnostic (this `date` function may not be available in other DBMS).

To fix that - add one more column, called `created_on` with type `date`, make sure you write the date on save and you're good to go:

```
Stats.order(created_on: :asc, random: :asc)
```

So, as you can see - you can trade some complexities in query for some complexity with `after_save` or `before_save` callbacks and some space in DB. You can decide if it's a good trade-off.